# Create multiple Hyperlinks in single table cell using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I wish to create a table cell, which would be filled with comma-separated hyperlinks. All should be in one cell. What happens based on the code below is that for each hyperlink a new cell is created... Both code versions below lead to adding cells. Does anyone have an idea on how to do that?

```
<td th:each="element: ${todo.getAssigneeList()}">
  <span>
    <a th:text="|${element.getId()}, |" th:href="@{/assignee/{id}/detail(id=${element.id})}"></a>
  </span>
</td>
```

---

```
<td th:each="element: ${todo.getAssigneeList()}"><a th:text="|${element.getId()}, |" th:href="@{/assignee/{id}/detail(id=${element.id})}"></a></td>
```

Below provided solution works as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may combine in your link both iteration and access to the elements. Thymeleaf [Attribute Precedence](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#attribute-precedence) will first parse iteration and only after that will parse the access to the variables ...

```
<td><a th:each="element: ${todo.getAssigneeList()}"
    th:text="|${element.getId()}, |"
    th:href="@{/assignee/{id}/detail(id=${element.id})}"></a>
</td>
```

Yet another way to use a container tag (for example [<th:block>](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#synthetic-thblock-tag)). The code may look like ...

```
<td>
    <th:block th:each="element: ${todo.getAssigneeList()}">
        <a th:text="|${element.getId()}, |"
            th:href="@{/assignee/{id}/detail(id=${element.id})}"></a>
    </th:block>
</td>
```